# AWS::S3::Bucket LambdaConfiguration in multiple AWS Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have 4 AWS Lambdas that should read S3 bucket when some file is created (S3 Event), but in cloudformation I just can use 1 Lambda ARN, see inside `AWS::S3::Bucket LambdaConfiguration`:

[image]

How can I trigger more than 1 Lambda in Bucket Lambda Configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS recently announced [S3 Event Notifications with Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-use-amazon-s3-event-notifications-with-amazon-eventbridge/). Consequently, you can enable EventBridge notification on your bucket and then have one (or more) Lambda function(s) triggered by those events.

Example implementation using AWS SAM:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: 'S3 EventBridge Example'

Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: 'Name of the bucket to be created'

Resources:

  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        EventBridgeConfiguration:
          EventBridgeEnabled: true

  S3EventProcessor:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: S3EventListener
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Handler: index.handler
      InlineCode: |
        exports.handler = (event, context) => {
          console.log('event:', JSON.stringify(event));
        }
      Events:
        S3EventBridgeRule:
          Type: EventBridgeRule
          Properties:
            Pattern:
              source:
                - aws.s3
              detail:
                bucket:
                  name:
                    - !Ref BucketName
```

Answer (score 2):

S3 does not offer this kind of fan-out out-of-the-box but only through e.g. SNS.
You need to push the notification into a SNS topic instead of a lambda and then either

- subscribe four lambdas to that topic or
- subscribe four queues to the topic and let each lambda "subscribe" to one queue

Answer (score 1):

I think [Step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/step-functions/) is exactly what you want. Also [S3-related tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/compute/synchronizing-amazon-s3-buckets-using-aws-step-functions/) can be useful